# Run BASH script from .PHP file

Tags: php, linux, shell

Bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir /var/www/html/bash
```

PHP file:

```
<?php
exec("/var/www/html/bash.sh");
?>
```

After I enter `localhost/phpfile.php` `/var/www/html/bash` directory Is not created. I tried `shell_exec` command no results as well. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does the PHP user have permissions to create directories?

Comment: `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   40 Nov  7 18:47 phpfile.php`
`-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   39 Nov  7 18:46 bashfile.sh`  files are in root group so they should have it. Am I wrong?

Comment: PHP is not a user in the root group.

Comment: First find the user for Apache `sudo ps aux |grep apache`  or `sudo ps aux |grep httpd`  On my server I get `www-data`  So, to allow it to create directories, I chmod the parent folder 775, then `chgrp www-data /parentdir`   ps chmod and chgrp will also need to be done via sudo

Comment: @JayBlanchard can you tell me how to do it? Or maybe you could give me a link, where I can read more about it.

Comment: You do not want PHP in your root group. Follow what @DuaneLortie says above.

Comment: @DuaneLortie worked just fine. Can you post this as a answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely failing because Apache does not have write permissions within your `./var/www/html` directory. To give Apache the necessary permissions, try this...

First find the user for Apache 
`sudo ps aux |grep apache`  or `sudo ps aux |grep httpd`

On my server I get www-data So, to allow it to create directories, I chmod the parent folder 775, `sudo chmod 775 /var/www/html`

Then, change the group owner to the user that runs apache (www-data in my case)

`sudo chgrp www-data /var/www/html`